# Input text to link with a form?

Tags: html

I've been working on having a form where a user can input a subreddits name in a input form and be taken to it, but not been working out well. **I've tried using get** and **name="q"** but it makes the address funky.

What I have so far:

```
<form method="post" action="http://www.reddit.com/r/" style="margin-left:5px;margin-right:5px;margin-bottom:0px;">
    <input class="form-control" value="" placeholder="Subreddit Name">
</form>
```

**If you're not getting what i'm trying to do**: A user types text into an input, the text they typed would be sent to an address as *reddit.com/r/*(whatever the user typed)

Comment: Can you use JavaScript?  Otherwise, you'll have to post to your own server and redirect from there.  POST sends information to a server in the header information, not in the URL.

Comment: @Jonathan I understand what you're saying with post, but when I do use get it just adds stuff like ?r%20(whatever the user typed) after the link.

Comment: That's correct.  Using the GET method will post to the server via a query string (question mark followed by keys + data).  So the question remains: can you use JavaScript?  If not you'll have to redirect server-side on your own server.

Comment: I can use JavaScript yes, but where along the lines would I place the JavaScript in this situation?

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/js/

Comment: @whatever I've given an example as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not knowing from your question whether or not you have access to server-side coding, and based on your answers in the comments, the following should work for you.  Note that if a browser has JavaScript disabled, this will bring the user directly to http://www.redit.com/r/

If you have access to server-side scripting, you could add a catch on your server as well to avoid this.

```
<form method="post" onsubmit="document.location='http://www.reddit.com/r/'+document.getElementById('subredditname').value;return false;" action="http://www.reddit.com/r/" style="margin-left:5px;margin-right:5px;margin-bottom:0px;">
  <input id="subredditname" class="form-control" value="" placeholder="Subreddit Name">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this easily with PHP.

User types text into input field

```
<input type="text" name="user_text" />
```

After form submit, run PHP code

```
$page = $_POST['user_text'];
//send user to website
header('Location: http://reddit.com/r/' . $page);
```